# UI for dismissing View Controller presented by UIPopoverPresentationController regardless of Size Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a Universal app, Xcode 7 Beta, targeting iOS 8.

I am presenting a View Controller using `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

When presented in any Regular Size Class (e.g. Full screen iPad in any orientation), the View Controller appears as a popover, at the size I have set in the `preferredContentSize` property. A tap outside the bounds of the View Controller will dismiss the popover.

When presented in Compact Width Size Class (e.g. any iPhone in portrait orientation), the "popover" will become a full screen view, sliding in from the bottom to the top.

**The Problem**

While an iPad popover has built-in dismissal behaviour (i.e. tap outside of the popover), "popovers" presented full-screen do not. And thus need some UI in order to provide the user with a way to dismiss the popover.

**Question**

What is the best (recommended?) way to present a UI such that it only appears for the Compact Width Size Class, in order to give the user an option to dismiss the (full screen) "popover" View Controller?

**Discussion**

One approach I have seen is to embed the [View Controller to be presented] in a `UINavigationController`. A bar button is added to the Navigation Bar, though whose outlet we can tell the presenting View Controller to dismiss the presentation.

However, not only does this require an extra, unwanted hierarchy for the otherwise simple presented View Controller on the iPad, but it requires environment checking (idiom? size class?) in `viewDidLoad` to programmatically hide the `NavigationBar` if a Regular Width Size Class (e.g. iPad) is being used. This strikes me as... fragile.

Another option is to do the above, but use Size Classes within Interface Builder to *Install/Uninstall* the Navigation elements, non-programmatically.

Thoughts?

Related link, [discussing the detection of popover mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687017/ios-8-presentationcontroller-determine-if-really-is-popover/27037928#27037928)

Answer (score 0):

Look at Interface Builder, you can make available any view depending on the Size Class currently running on your app :) If i remember well (because I can't check for now as I'm in a bus) you can specify a view to be available in a specific Size Class in the Property Inspector tab of the selected view. That way you just have to add a button or a navigation bar with items in your view and make it available only for Compact widths :) I'll check more specificaly today to take you some screenshots :)